# Approach on how to serialize this xml as input for a webservice method

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, serialization

I got a webreference in my project and all of the methods I can call to consume data from the system return Datasets with information (sometimes multiple tables inside one dataset). In my code I don't have anything strong typed at this point which feel al bit unlucky to be honest. I can consume data from some of the GetAll methods that are exposed in this webservices. Some of the methods I have to call to search for the right data require me to send xml as a parameter to a method. This is the format that is expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProductSearchCriteria>
  <dictionary xmlns="http://dff.com/xml/serialization">
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_Ages</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <ArrayOfInt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="">
          <int>-1</int>
          <int>-1</int>
        </ArrayOfInt>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_CityId</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <int xmlns="">0</int>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_CountryId</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <int xmlns="">140</int>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_CultureName</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <int xmlns="">2</int>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_FromDate</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <dateTime xmlns="">2009-11-07T00:00:00</dateTime>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_IncludePaxRulesDescriptionText</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <int xmlns="">1</int>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_PageNumber</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <int xmlns="">1</int>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_PageSize</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <int xmlns="">10</int>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_Pax</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <int xmlns="">2</int>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_ProdObjIds</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <ArrayOfInt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" />
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_ProdObjTypes</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <ArrayOfInt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" />
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_ProdTypes</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <ArrayOfInt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" />
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_RegionAreaId</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <int xmlns="">430</int>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_ResortId</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <int xmlns="">0</int>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_SalesChannelId</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <int xmlns="">2</int>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_ShowAvailableProdsOnly</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <int xmlns="">0</int>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_StarRating</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <ArrayOfInt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="">
          <int>0</int>
          <int>1</int>
          <int>2</int>
          <int>3</int>
          <int>4</int>
          <int>5</int>
        </ArrayOfInt>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_ThemeId</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <int xmlns="">2</int>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string xmlns="">Prod_ToDate</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <dateTime xmlns="">2009-11-14T00:00:00</dateTime>
      </value>
    </item>
  </dictionary>
</ProductSearchCriteria>
```

Now I have been searching for the best way to be able to send this expected xml format as a parameter (string) in the method of this webservice, but I can't seem to find a good solid solution which feels save. I would like to just build a class which I can xml serialize (with a dictionary with different types).
Would be helped alot with some good suggestions!

Comment: Is there a schema (XSD) available for the XML you are expected to send/receive? If so have a look at how far "xsd.exe" will generate the classes for you.

Comment: There is no xsd available to generate a class unfortunately.